# Check if a file is readable as a BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Is there a way to check a File is readable as a BufferedImage without doing the try with ImageIO.read(File) ?

I could eventually extract the mime type of the file, but is there a list of defaultly supported mime types for BufferedImage or something like that?

Comment: Do be host, by the time you extract the mime type, look up the available service providers and determine if any can actually read the mime type, it would have be faster a simpler to just do ImageIO.read and catch the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about defaultly, but `ImageIO.getReaderMIMETypes()` will give you the list of *currently* supported readers.

The correct thing to do is probably to try `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)` - if it doesn't throw an IOException, but returns null, the image is not readable.

Note that `ImageIO.read(file)` will also *not* throw an exception for an unsupported MIME format, it will return null. Exceptions will only be thrown for a supported file that can't be decoded (ie the file is corrupted), or IO errors (obviously).

Comment: Thanks! I read the javadoc too fast and didn't notice it was only throwing when there was an error, and returning null when not an image :)